# Nonce validation in REST API

Tags: rest-api, nonce, previews

I am creating a headless Wordpress website. Wordpress backend (port 8888), VueJS frontend (port 8081). Data is loaded via REST API. This works fine.

Now I want to implement the preview-functionality. Therefore I wrote some code to get a JWT token to authenticate. After that I want to get the draft/preview data by requesting this URL (with bearer token header):

```
http://localhost:8888/wp-json/wp/v2/pages/11?preview_id=11&_wpnonce=01c024a8ed&preview=true&acf_format=standard&status=draft
```

This fails because of a nonce-validation error. I looked into the `wp_create_nonce` and `wp_verify_nonce` functions, and found out they use a token by calling `wp_get_session_token()`. When I click the preview button in the Wordpress backend, it uses the session token from the active session to generate the nonce. This session, however, is different from the session that is created by the JWT authentication. Therefore the nonces are different and the validation of the nonce fails.

How can I solve this issue?
Overwriting the `wp_create_nonce` and `wp_verify_nonce` functions and leaving out the `wp_get_session_token()` doesn't feel like a good solution.

Thanks!